# FontAwesome overridden by other css styling classes

Tags: html, css, overriding, font-awesome, font-family

To avoid FontAwesome fonts could be hidden by css-classes specified for the containing tags, remember to always add 'FontAwesome' in the 'font-family' list of atmost one of such classes

Comment: are you asking or answering?

Comment: I flagged this post to be closed as 'Unclear what you asking' since I can't find any question or problem with your codes. Please read here [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a question.

Comment: `    <style>
    li a {
     font-family: FontAwesome, "Trebuchet MS", helvetica, sans !important;
    }
    </style>
    <h:form>
        <p:menu id="menu" style="padding-top:20px;">
         <p:submenu label="Menu Carpooling">
          <p:menuitem value="Notifiche" actionListener="#{iscrizioneCP.goToNotificheCarpooler()}" icon="fa fa-bell-o" styleClass="myBellIcon"/>`    ...

Comment: whats your question?